# Closed immersions and base change

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Consider a field extension $L\subseteq K$ and two $L$ schemes $X_L$ and $Y_L$ with an **embedding** $j:X_L\longrightarrow Y_L$. Now take the base changes 
$$X:=X_L\times_{\text{Spec L}}\text{Spec} K$$ 
$$Y:=Y_L\times_{\text{Spec L}}\text{Spec} K$$

We have the following commutative diagram:

[image]

If we know by hypotesis that $j\times\text{id}:X\longrightarrow Y$ is a **closed embedding**, then can we conclude that also $j$ was a **closed embedding**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Being a closed embedding is a local question so basically you're asking if $A \to B$ is an $L$-algebra map and $A\otimes K \to B \otimes K$ is surjective then is $A \to B$ surjective?  The answer to that is yes, because field extensions $L \to K$ are *faithfully flat*.